# BASH_VERSION is empty even though SHELL is /bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have run into an issue when executing script in /etc/profile.d/script.sh. On one of my machines (only this one, on the others it is running well), when I do

```
echo "$BASH_VERSION" >> /home/synek317/log
echo "$SHELL"        >> /home/synek317/log
```

the result is that `BASH_VERSION` is empty, but `SHELL` is `/bin/bash`. However, when I run terminal and type `echo $BASH_VERSION`, it is filled correctly.

I run this on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Do you have any ideas why is this variable empty during execution of `/etc/profile.d/` scripts?

Comment: this is fresh copy of ubuntu. It is empty only during login.

Comment: The only place I found is /usr/sbin/lightdm-session but it is the same on other machine...

Comment: `SHELL` is not necessarily the name of the current shell; it's the name of your login shell. The scripts in `/etc/profile.d` may be executed by `/bin/sh`, which is `dash` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Write env, set, $$, pwd, id, "ps -aef" and all such other things in to the file along with BASH_VERSION and SHELL. That should give you clues on what shell executed it and what was its environment like.

Comment: Thanks for the clues. I have found out that all of this is working, well, accidentally. The line in my profile.d script checks not empty BASH_VERSION or ZSH_VERSION. lightdm-session sets BASH_VERSION as empty var when launching profile scripts. So it means that my profile.d script works only because of ZSH_VERSION is set. Now the question is why on one machine it is set and on the other it is not. It is weird however.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, `/etc/profile.d` scripts are not run by Bash.

Comment: This answer is correct, but may leave you wondering who reads those scripts.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462663/purpose-of-n-ps1-in-bashrc#answer-462678